# WillPopScope producing error when returning to previous page

Tags: flutter, error-handling, navigation

I have recently added "WillPopScope" into a part of my code, however whenever I use it to return to the previous page, the page displays for like half a second before the below error appears on screen

```
    class _UserCommunicationState extends State<UserCommunication> {
   Future<bool?> showWarning(BuildContext context) async => showDialog<bool>(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => BackdropFilter(
                 filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 10, sigmaY: 10),
                child: 
                AlertDialog(
                title: Text('Would you like to cancel Alert?'),
                actions: [
                ElevatedButton(
                 onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, false),
                 child: 
             
                 Text('No')
                  ),
                 ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, true),
              child: Text('Yes'))
        ],
      ),
      )); 

return WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () async {
    print('Back Button pressed!');

    final shouldPop = await showWarning(context);
    return shouldPop ?? false;
  },
```

[error I get after using WillPopScope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnId5.png)

Answer (score 0):

that's because you pop the screen twice , once in the show warning method and the second one when you return true from this function , try to return false
in the onWillPop and the showWarning method will handle this logic.

Comment: onWillPop does return false though, the 

part where it's : return shouldPop ?? false

Comment: if you return true there's a pop will be triggered from the system , if false this pop will not be  triggered.